# Redux creating new objects on ui

Tags: redux

Creating an application that uses redux state quite seriously.

While passing values between the UI components and the reducers. The immutability has become a problem.

1) The cycle problem  - I have forms that create JSON objects - which are then used by reducers to maintain the model.  The next time you use a form, it is set to the earlier state,.. and either gives error or updates the previous attribute along with itself. Is there someway to capture things in non redux state and then pass it to the states for process?

2) Redux returns or reducers become extremely unmanageable on scale. I have started using immer for this. Is this a good choice?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Reactjs for creating the forms?

To benefit most from immutabilitiy it is best if your design embraces it also.
What I mean: Develop a form which just displays your data. (a pure form, or FormPure)

Then wrap this form / component by another component which holds the state of the form to be displayed and actually displays the data through the pure form. And allows you to just edit it.

The hierarchy would look like: App > Form > FormPure

- Components

  - Form:
  - - Connected to Redux
  - - May have its own state.
  - FormPure:
  - - Does not know about redux
  - - Only displays data provided from    its parent (in react via props       and communicated via callbacks up)

When the user hits the Save Button then the connected Component (Form) may dispatch an action to update the state in redux.

This way you may build your FormPure in isolation separately from any data, and just bring it to live as needed.

You may consider using [Storybook](https://storybook.js.org/) for nicely designing your components.

For 2: Yes immer is reasonably fine to use, just make sure you are not overusing it by creating to large object trees, as described in the documentation. 
Also make sure to turn off autofreezing when deploying it to production.

Hint: immer uses [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) make sure your target platform supports them, or make sure to switch then to the ES5 implementation which is considerably slower (see, [immer docs](https://immerjs.github.io/immer/docs/introduction))

Comment: I am am really liking  what you suggest - and it quite makes sense - it gives added benefit of freedom to keep styling and logic far apart!

Comment: It also allows you to test your form in isolation. once you wrote your FromPure, you will never have to touch that file ever again. you could simply wrap it by another Form to display other data. Try to keep components as small as possible and reuse them. I try to only connect as little components as possible to redux and create as many pure components as possible.